# Element doesn't show

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use the color picker from element-ui (http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/color-picker). However it doesn't show up... Any clues about whats wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="color">
    <span class="demonstration">Color picker</span>
    <el-color-picker v-model="color"></el-color-picker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import ColorPicker from 'element-ui'
  Vue.use(ColorPicker)

  export default {
    name: 'color',
    data () {
      return {
        color: '#20a0ff'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you may want to do: `import {ColorPicker} from 'element-ui';`

Comment: Didn't change anything, still not showing. Also wouldn't that only be if I'm importing more than one component?

Comment: import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css' after   import ColorPicker from 'element-ui'

Comment: @Deepak - That worked! I wonder why it's invisible by default... but anyway, if you create a proper answer I'll accept that.

Comment: @user672009 answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the default-theme css too:

```
<template>
  <div class="color">
    <span class="demonstration">Color picker</span>
    <el-color-picker v-model="color"></el-color-picker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import ColorPicker from 'element-ui'
  import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'
  Vue.use(ColorPicker)

  export default {
    name: 'color',
    data () {
      return {
        color: '#20a0ff'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Reference: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart#import-element